# Zend Framework 2 Redirect not working

Tags: redirect, zend-framework2

i have a problem with ZF2 not redirecting from my controller. When i call the url xyz.dev/event it redirects to my home ("/") as defined in routes. When i call xyz.dev/event/1 (where id is now set) it shall also redirect to home, which is not happening. I get the error

```
Url plugin requires that controller event compose a router; none found
```

My code is here:

```
namespace Event\Controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\SimpleRouteStack;
use Event\Model\EventTable;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController {

    protected $eventsTable;
    public $event;
    public $_event;

    public function indexAction() {
        $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
        if (!$id) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute("home");
        }

        $this->event = $this->getEventsTable()->getEvent($id);

//        if ($this->event->end < date("Y-m-d")) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home');
//        }
        return new ViewModel(array("event" => $this->event));
    }




    public function getEventsTable() {

        if (!$this->eventsTable) {
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->eventsTable = $sm->get("Event\Model\EventTable");
        }
        return $this->eventsTable;
    }

}
```

The first redirect

```
if (!$id) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute("home");
        }
```

is working fine, the second is not... Any ideas?
Thank you,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Check your module.config file routing section and check which has proper routing condition as like below:

```
   'home' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/home[/:action][/:id][/]',
                'constraints' => array(                     
                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'id' => '[0-9]*',   
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Home\Controller\Home',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

You may forgot to mention the optional parameters(**id**) in your routing arguments.

I hope this works...